# Reading the value of Javascript array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have declared an array as

`dataLayer[{}];`

in `onclick` i have written a function

`onclick="dataLayer.push({'event':'xing'})";`

How do i get the value of event when a `onclick` happens?

Comment: You should declare your array as `dataLayer[]`, otherwise you're adding an empty object to the 0 index of the array.

Comment: `dataLayer[{ }];` should `dataLayer = [];`

Comment: so is it like dataLayer[0]['event'] ?

Comment: `dataLayer[dataLayer.length-1]['event']` for the last item, and `dataLayer[0]['event']` for the first item

Comment: `dataLayer[i]['event']` or `dataLayer[i].event`, that's equivalent (but the second one is more elegant).